# How to specify different color for a specific year value range in a single figure? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I've a time-series dataset, from 1992-2017. I can set a color for the whole data dots but what I want is to set desired color for specific year range. For Example; from 1992-1995 "Blue", from 1995-2005 "Red" etc. How can we do that?

Dataset has 2 columns; year and value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import linear_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Atlantic = pd.read_csv('C:\\AtlanticEnd.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

X = Atlantic['year']

y = Atlantic['Poseidon']

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.ylabel('Change in mean sea level [mm]', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Atlantic Ocean - Mean Sea Level', fontsize=20)
colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "purple"]
texts = ["Poseidon", "Jason1", "Jason2", "Jason3"]
patches = [ plt.plot([],[], marker="o", ms=10, ls="", mec=None, color=colors[i], 
            label="{:s}".format(texts[i]) )[0]  for i in range(len(texts)) ]
plt.legend(handles=patches, loc='upper left', ncol=1, facecolor="grey", numpoints=1 )

plt.plot(X, y, 'ro', color='red')

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X, y)
plt.plot(X, X*slope+intercept, 'b')

plt.axis([1992, 2018, -25, 80])

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()

def trendline(Atlantic, order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(Atlantic.index.values, list(Atlantic), order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)

slope = trendline(y)
print(slope)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slO60.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Provide sample data and tell us what you did:  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code and output picture added.

Answer (score 3):

I could imagine that using a colormap for a scatter plot of the points may be an easy solution. The scatter's color would then simply be defined by the year, assuming the year is given in decimal format. A `BoundaryNorm` would define the ranges for the values and a colormap can easily be created from a list of colors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

y =  np.random.rand(300)*26+1992
d = (3.075*(y-1992)-17)+np.random.normal(0,5,300)
df = pd.DataFrame({"year" : y, "data" : d})

bounds = [1992,1995,2005,2015,2018]
colors = ["darkorchid", "crimson", "limegreen", "gold"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(colors))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(df.year, df.data, c=df.year.values, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(sc, spacing="proportional")

fit = np.polyfit(df.year.values, df.data.values, deg=1)
ax.plot(df.year, np.poly1d(fit)(df.year.values), color="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made my own random data for this function to work but assuming you have non-overlapping date ranges, this should work. It also seemed like your dates are not of `pd.datetime` type. This should work for `pd.datetime` types but your lookup values in the dictionary will be something like `("1992-01-01","2000-01-01")` and so on.

```
# Create data
data = np.random.rand(260,1)
dates = np.array(list(range(1992,2018))*10)

df = pd.DataFrame({"y":data[:,0],"date":dates})
df = df.sort(columns="date")

# Dictionary lookup
lookup_dict = {(1992,2000):"r", (2001,2006):"b",(2007,2018):"k"}

# Slice data and plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for lrange in lookup_dict:
    temp = df[(df.date>=lrange[0]) & (df.date<=lrange[1])]
    ax.plot(temp.date,temp.y,color=lookup_dict[lrange], marker="o",ls="none")
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: exactly what i am looking for!! Thanks Matt! Somehow I am biased in thinking that support for R is much greater than python ;)